# Content of stepper does not scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm currently developing an app.
For this, I used the flutter stepper, but I have the problem that the inner content is not scrollable, I already tried several possibilities, but unsuccessfully. 
I have inserted image + code
I hope you can help me.

Picture:

[image]
Stepper:

```
  body: Container(
            child: Stepper(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              steps: stepsStammdaten(),
              currentStep: currentStep,
              onStepContinue: next,
              onStepTapped: (step) => goTo(step),
              onStepCancel: cancel,
            ),


Step(
          state: StepState.indexed,
          isActive: true,
          title: const Text('Rejkla'),
          content: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: this.index,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => this._buildRow(index),
            )
          ),´´´

The method buildRow() contains a ListView

 return ListView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[

// Here are some text inputs

]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `code` works perfect for me.
By Replacing your below code

```
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
```

with this

```
physics : ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

*It should be able to scroll perfectly.*

Comment: Hey, yes the scrolling works, but I would like to scroll in the red container and not in the white one. See picture ->  https://imgur.com/eb37lBg.png

Comment: For scrolling your red container you should wrap your red container into a SingleChildScrollView or in a Listview, btw Please Accept the answer if it was helpfull to you.

Comment: Hey, I tried the ListView and the SingleChildScrollView, but it didn't work. Scrolling outside works perfectly, but not in the red area. Your answer is correct, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Let me try to help you then, can you provide your code or a link to the code ?

Comment: Actually in my opinion you have to give your red container a height say 600 and then wrap it in the singlechildscrollview and then it should scroll, but if this doesn't help you , then please provide me the code link and I will look into that.

Comment: return Container(
        height: 600,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: SizedBox(
                height: 600,
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[]))); - i tried this one, but also doenst work :/

Comment: Actually this is not sufficient to find out the exact problem, will you mind showing more code to solve the problem

Comment: And you have to wrap your container into the SingleChildScrollView but instead you wraped your SingleChildScrollView into the container, try fixing this first.

Comment: This solution works for me -> SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
          child: new Column(children: <Widget>[])]);

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both of you Mukul and CodOg. I also got stuck in the same kind of problem, and I read your conversation, its helped me a lot to solve the problem. I tried this one. And this one is working.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddMember extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddMemberState createState() => _AddMemberState();
}

class _AddMemberState extends State<AddMember> {
  int _currentStep = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('ADD MEMBERS'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      body: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.orange),
        child: Form(
          child: new Stepper(
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            steps: _myStep(),
            currentStep: this._currentStep,
            onStepTapped: (step) {
              setState(() {
                this._currentStep = step;
              });
            },
            onStepContinue: () {
              setState(() {
                if (this._currentStep < this._myStep().length - 1) {
                  this._currentStep = this._currentStep + 1;
                } else {
                  print('Completed, Check the Filed');
                }
              });
            },
            onStepCancel: () {
              setState(() {
                if (this._currentStep > 0) {
                  this._currentStep = this._currentStep - 1;
                } else {
                  this._currentStep = 0;
                }
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Step> _myStep() {
    List<Step> _steps = [
      Step(
        title: Text('Personal Details'),
        content: new Container(
          height: 500,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextFormField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "First Name",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new TextFormField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "First Name",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new TextFormField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "First Name",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new TextFormField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "First Name",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
          ),
        ),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text('Residence Details'),
        content: Form(child: TextField()),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 1,
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text('Office Details'),
        content: Form(child: TextField()),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 2,
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text('Native Details'),
        content: Form(child: TextField()),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 3,
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text('Others Details'),
        content: Form(child: TextField()),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 4,
      ),
    ];
    return _steps;
  }
}
```